# Is machine learning only about estimating programs?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, pac-learning

**Q:** Can we say that all of machine learning is, essentially, only about finding good estimations of programs? If not, is there any example of a machine learning problem that is not about finding estimations of programs?

Examples of programs could be simple decision problem solvers, such as binary classification, regression, clustering, or more complicated programs such as those that generate special sequences of output (e.g. instructions for a self-drive automotive, human text, audio signals, etc).

---

Some definitions in case it helps clarifying the context.

A program is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program) as follows:

> A computer program is a collection of instructions that performs a
>   specific task when executed by a computer. A computer requires
>   programs to function, and typically executes the program's
>   instructions in a central processing unit.

Machine learning is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program) as follows:

> Machine learning is a subfield of computer science that evolved
>   from the study of pattern recognition and computational learning
>   theory in artificial intelligence. In 1959, Arthur Samuel defined
>   machine learning as a "Field of study that gives computers the ability
>   to learn without being explicitly programmed". Machine learning
>   explores the study and construction of algorithms that can learn from
>   and make predictions on data. Such algorithms operate by building a
>   model from example inputs in order to make data-driven predictions or
>   decisions, rather than following strictly static program
>   instructions.

Comment: This question is confusing to me because I'm not familiar with exactly what "estimation of programs" means, and from your examples, it's not clear what is *not* a program.

Comment: Estimating programs means finding a program that is closest possible to the true program that you ideally want to identify. Usually you estimate such programs by only analyzing the previous outputs of the true program. And yes, I too think that everything is a program. So I guess the answer to this question is a *yes*?

Comment: If your question is "Is machine learning only about estimating *something*?", then it seems safe to say "yes". If your question is "Is machine learning only about estimating *something* based **only** analyzing previous results of that *something*?", one could say the answer is "no", with Bayesian methods being a counter example: you are estimating *something* using both observations *and* expert knowledge. But I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're after.

Comment: I am after a bigger question. It's all coming as multiple specific questions instead of a single big question. I also agree about everything you said in your comment.

Comment: Whuber, is the edit enough?

Comment: The definition of *program* that you provide specifies that it must be "executed by a computer". Clearly ML is used to estimate relationships that aren't run on or generated by a computer. So that's a rather trivial *no*, but it's probably not what you're after.

Comment: @gung I think by *computer* they mean anything that computes things. So a human brain is a computer too (just a biological one).

Comment: "Anything that computes things" is pretty vague. I think this is going to end up being an exercise in definitions. You come up w/ a definition that makes the answer trivially no, or a different definition that makes the answer trivially yes.

Comment: Maybe my definitions are wrong. Could you please suggest corrections to my definitions?

Comment: @gung also it is fine if the answer is trivial. This is an easy question, that I want to be sure about, and it is part of a series of questions (out of which this is the easiest).

Comment: I meant "you [could] come up w/ a definition...". Whether the answer is *yes* or *no* only depends on how you decide to define the terms.

Comment: @gung so? That's true with everything. This is why people try to use definitions that are correct or highly agreeable. I don't get your point. Are you implying that my definitions are unclear or wrong? If so, I'd like to know the corrections to reach agreeable definitions.

Answer (score 8):

The paper [On the Learnability of the Uncomputable](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~rickl/publications/1996-icml.pdf) showes that machine learning is not estimating programs in a very surprising direction.
It shows how to [pac learn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probably_approximately_correct_learning) the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).
The halting problem is not computable, and therefore there is no program that can compute it.

The way to learn it is simple - take a large enough sample of programs that halt. Compute a threshold high enough so most programs halt before it. When having to classify a new sample run it until the threshold and see if it halts.

I think that this paper shouldn't be interpreted as showing that we can learn what we cannot compute. Instead, in alerts on the problem in the PAC framework. We assume that if we have samples, we can learn. In the case of the halting problem, we cannot get such samples (in general). Without extra knowledge we won't know which of the programs will eventually halt so we can run time until they end.

In the other direction, formal treatment of machine learning usually assume that the concept belong to some hypothesis set of a mathematical nature. Usually most concept discussed belong to much simpler hypothesis classes than programs. The reason to that is that we have negative results about the learnability for already when the concept is less complex than a program. For examples see "[Cryptographic limitations on learning boolean formulae and finite automata](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/crypto.pdf)"

Comment: But PAC learning aims to find an *estimation* of a solver that solves the halting problem. However, it will never be able to find a solver for it (it will always have errors). I don't think that there is any claim that a program cannot estimate the solver of the halting problem, and as far as I know PAC learning is about finding estimators (not actual solvers). Just to make sure I read correctly: are you saying that estimators of solvers of the halting problems are not programs?

Comment: There is no program that can solve the halting problem. However, this paper shows how one can estimate this inexistent solver. The key point here is that PAC learning assumes that you will have a dataset of labeled sample. Hence the claim is "Given labeled samples for halting programs, one can estimate the inexistent halting problem problem".  The next step should be - since we know that one cannot solve the halting problem (in general), then one cannot build a dataset on halting problem (in general).

Comment: The in general is for estimating the halting problem on arbitrary cases. Of course that one can find many samples of program that stop/don't stop.

Comment: I see how that is evidence that enough dataset cannot be found, but I cannot see how that is evidence that the resultant classification model is not a program.

Comment: Oh, I understand. The resultant model is indeed a program. The concept that the model tries to learn cannot be implemented in a program.

Comment: So I guess that means that PAC learning is about estimating a subset of programs? And therefore saying that machine learning is about estimating (at least a subset of) programs is not refuted yet?

Comment: You can say even more - PAC is about estimating mathematical concepts. These mathematical concepts can be implemented  by programs. We actually know how to learn simple mathematical concepts and we have negative results about some more complex concepts.

Comment: Can the PAC estimations of mathematical concepts happen without running a program?

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. There are PAC algorithms that run on a dataset and produce a concept as an estimation. The concept itself is not being run as a program while learning.

Comment: Who cares about the concept behind PAC learning. My question is about "is machine learning about estimating programs?". The answer that I found in IRC channels is "yes". Your PAC learning is not an evidence against this. PAC learning still produces estimations, which are programs.  Btw thank you for linking the paper, I was the 1st to give you a +1 cause you linked a peer reviewed paper which is ultra awesome.

Comment: You don't have to choose the PAC framework to be your definition of machine learning. Indeed, there are also other frameworks an which you will get different results. As an example for  a total different framework, you can see Gold's language identification in the limit http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/spring2010/readings/gold67limit.pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification_in_the_limit

Comment: None of them show any thing that would contradict the claim that machine learning is confined within the prediction/finding of programs.